Use of DS_START_DATE in formulas?
What I have :

event data with a Start date and a End date

Problem :

if the event starts before the DS_START_DATE and ends after the DS_END_DATE, it will never be displayed anywhere

Stack : Google Sheets data synced with Looker Studio, no BigQuery involved
Question : Is there a way to retrieve DS_START_TIME and DS_END_TIME to use it in filters/calculations/etc... ?
Thx :)
What I want :

when the report user selects a time span via the built-in time picker, the report displays all events occuring at this moment

